# How to loop through Pandas DataFrame and split a string into multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What would be the best way to loop through a dataframe with strings that I would like to split into multiple rows while retaining the other value at the same time?

input:

```
genres                   revenue
action|comedy|drama       5000
action|romance            10000
```

output:

```
genres      revenue
action      5000
comedy      5000
drama       5000
action      10000
romance     10000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with assign back column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), last for default index add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df1=df.assign(genres = df['genres'].str.split('|')).explode('genres').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
    genres  revenue
0   action     5000
1   comedy     5000
2    drama     5000
3   action    10000
4  romance    10000
```

Comment: this solution is very helpful and I strongly recommend it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

**Note: `df.explode` works for pandas version >= 0.25**

```
In [2240]: df.genres = df.genres.str.split('|')

In [2242]: df = df.explode('genres')

In [2243]: df
Out[2243]: 
    genres  revenue
0   action     5000
0   comedy     5000
0    drama     5000
1   action    10000
1  romance    10000
```